# Is it working correctly for timer?

Tags: javascript, timer

HTML:

```
<div id="timer"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
timer.innerHTML = "100";
var yoursite = "http://explame.com"

var mytimer = document.getElementById("timer")

setInterval(function() {
    mytimer.innerHTML -= 1; 

    if(mytimer.innerHTML == '1') {
        setTimeout(function(){
            location.href=yoursite
        })
    };
}, 1000);
```

I want to create a timer... My timer now is working... Good :D

Comment: "I can't publish it before trying." ... what?

Comment: JSFiddle is your friend here: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Start identing your code.

Comment: You could also try to add all this to a .htm/.html file with the minimal required tags and see if you get the expected result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may try this:

```
var timer = 100;
var yoursite = "http://explame.com";
var mytimer = document.getElementById("timer");
mytimer.innerHTML = timer; 

var interval = setInterval(function() {
    timer--;
    mytimer.innerHTML = timer; 

    if (timer == 1) {
        location.href = yoursite;
        window.clearInterval(interval);
    }
}, 1000);
```

See it working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zg8p3/).

About the code:

- Keep using `;` at the end of each line;
- I've used a numeric variable to hold the timer count, because isn't a best practice(and awful too) to do arithmetic operations with string(like you're doing `mydiv.innerHTML -= 1`). To do this you'll have to use some cast functions, so it's simpler to use a numeric var;
- I don't see why to use a `setTimeOut` to call `location.href`, so I removed it;
- I have clean the interval at the end of the process.

Hope it helps. Good luck.

Comment: `textContent` instead of `innerHTML` will be faster.

Comment: @Pavlo because of **one** call in a second? This would be irrelevant.

Comment: Agree, performance gain will be negligible. But a good habit to develop is to use a tool appropriate for the job. In this case, it's `textContent`.

Comment: I completely agree with you, it's absolutely awful to use the innerHTML string as a counter instead of a `Number`, but (unfortunately) "thanks" to javascript type cohercion,you **can** do `stringNumber -= 1`, it does work :) see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZB9Te/)

Comment: @ArtoAle yeah you're right because the engine casts it implicitly.. I didn't paid attention to that. I fixed the text. Thank you.